# EF Core Buffered load of Included entities

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a query with Include:

```
dbContext.Set<Person>().Include(x => x.Events)
```

There will be 10s of Persons, but 10000s of Events for each Person.

I am looking for a generic buffering solution to not use too much memory at any given time.

If I use Skip and Take, the pagination will be done on the Person entity, so a Skip(1) would result in skipping all 10000 of Person1's Events. But for other Persons it will still load 10000s of Events each.

How can I load the nested entity rows in batches of say 100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF Core team implemented this 4 days before I asked the question. It should be available soon.

They call it [Filtered Include](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/1833#issuecomment-603543685).